# Validate Store Code and Redirect

Tags: magento-1.9, template, multistore, redirect

I have input field in **`Header.phtml`** and user can enter store code.If the store code is valid it should redirect to 
`Website/store/{storecode}/index.php.`

Can you please tell shortest way to validate the store code and redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your code in Url and used below code for validate of your code,

```
$Stores=array();
$storeCollection=Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection();
foreach($storeCollection as $store)
{
   $storelang= Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $store->getId());
   if(!isset($Stores[$storelang])){
           $Stores[$storelang]=array();
           $Stores[$storelang]['store']=array();
   }
   $Stores[$storelang]['lang']=$storelang;
   $Stores[$storelang]['store']=$store->getData();
}
$storeCode = array();
foreach($Stores as $eachstore)
{
 $storeCode[] = $eachstore['store']['store_code'];  
}


if(in_array($_REQUEST['code'],$storeCode)){
  //ReDirect your store url    
}else{
   //stay on same url and show error popup;
}
```

Hope this is of you.

Comment: Thanks Dhrumin. Can you please guide me how to handle the submit action , as i am beginner can you please elaborate.

Comment: Yes sure, first you need to elaborate your issue in so i replay on same.